# Select items between two dates, varchar format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table who contains a field 'date' which is a date in varchar format ("2016-07-30"). I would like to select all items which are between the date of today and the date of today +1 month. I already done the variable who contains the two dates (in date format) but I don't know how to select items between these two dates because the field of my table is in varchar and not in date format.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: use mysql string to date function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: You should really convert your  `varchar` to `date` in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select * 
from yourtable
where str_to_date(datecol, '%Y-%m-%d') between now() and date_add(now(), interval 1 month)
```

But the right thing you should do is alter your column type to `date`.